# How to integrate API data in highcharts react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, highcharts

I have created this chart in react using highcharts. Now I want to replace the static data with the JSON I'm getting from an Api.

[image: Donut Chart]

This is the static data:

```
series: [{data: [['Food',30], ['Travel',10], ['Groceries',20], ['Fuel',40]]}]
```

and this is what I'm getting from my API:

```
{
    "Fashion": 40.0,
    "TotalAmountSpent": 20000.0,
    "Food": 60.0
}
```

I want to convert this JSON into an array like

```
Data : [['Fashion',40],['Food',60]]
```

and then load this array into the chart options as

```
series: [{
             data: Data
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data to the structure required by Highcharts. For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // const data = API call
    const processedData = [];
    for (let key in data) {
      processedData.push([key, data[key]]);
    }

    setOptions({
      series: [{
        data: processedData
      }]
    });
  }, []);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-2qvsyt?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update